# Finding out which version PHP a remote server is running

Tags: php

I can't imagine this is possible but maybe there's some novel way. I'm developing an app which will require a few php files to be deployed and run on the clients' webservers. I'm not particularly interested in targeting clients who are still running pre version 5 versions of PHP.

So is there any way one can tell which version of PHP a remote webserver has running?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a site to view http headers such as http://web-sniffer.net/

Some sites will return the PHP version in the server section of the header for example here's a response from a site I just tested:

```
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 
mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 PHP/5.2.12
```

This is more likely to work on sites hosted on a standard shared hosting platform such as cPanel.

Comment: Also did the job. Didn't expect so many responses but I'll give you the tick as I re-install my development environment quite often and a website means one less tool to download.

Answer (score 7):

Many servers provide an X-Powered-By header which might include the PHP version. Try querying the server with curl:

```
curl -I http://example.com
```

Comment: Worked great on the few sites I tried. Thanks. I'll vote your answer up when I reach enough points to do so.

Comment: Also curl the www version of the website if you receive a "301 Moved Permanently" error

Answer (score 2):

You can olso view X-Powered-By header using some browser add-ons, for example "Live HTTP Headers" add-on to Mozilla Firefox. 
However most production servers doesn't include X-Powered-By header.

Comment: I'll keep it in mind. I'll vote your answer up when I reach enough points to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In fiddler, go to the compose tab and type in the web address and send a GET request. Then when the response pops up in the left window, double click on it. On the right side it'll showt he request and response details. In the response details (bottom right), click the RAW or HEADERS tab and take a look at the headers. The server info will be next to the Server: header